Linq aggregating on subgroups
Here is sample table :



Type
Item
Activity
Done




A
Item#1
Act#1
True


A
Item#1
Act#2
True


A
Item#1
Act#3
False


A
Item#2
Act#1
True


A
Item#2
Act#2
True


B
Item#3
Act#1
False


B
Item#3
Act#2
True


B
Item#3
Act#3
False



Output aggregation Should be :



Type
ItemsCount
ItemsDone
ItemsRemaining
ActivityCount
ActivityDone
ActivityRemain




A
2
1
1
5
4
1


B
1
0
1
3
1
2



Here is my Trial :
var _result = _itemModel.GroupBy(x => new { x.Type})
                        .Select(y => new
                         {
                           ItemsCount = y.Select(x => x.Item).Distinct().Count(),
                           ItemsDone= ????,
                           ItemsRemaining=????,
                           ActivityCount= y.Count(x => x.Type != null),
                           ActivityDone = y.Count(x => x.Completed == true),
                           ActivityReamin = y.Count(x => x.Completed == false)
                                     }).ToList();

I Try to count by Item as subgroup inside Type group.
Kindly correct and complete my code. appreciate your support

Try:
ItemsDone = y.GroupBy(x => x.Item).Count(g => g.All(i => i.Done)) name

or Completed instead of Done, not clear from your question what should be the property name

It works perfectly. for ItemsRemaining i use ItemsRemaining = y.GroupBy(x => x.Item).Count(g => !g.All(i => i.Completed==true)) i don't know if there is better formula

@Hussein I think that is good, I would use exactly the same expression :)
